# how make visual host in centos7 litespeed

Tags: centos, vhost, satellite

My website show in port 8080 in server.

How connect my domain name to `IPSERVER:8080`

Server: CentOS 7 - Litespeed

I have little information in this regard

Comment: Are you asking how to set up a domain name?  How to configure your web server to use a domain name you already own?

Comment: @jsbillings i use  (nodejs  - nextjs) site after run `npm start` show website in port 8080`54.36.XX.XX:8080`.I want to set the domain on this port

Comment: Do you own a domain?  Have you pointed it at that IP?

Comment: @jsbillings Yeah . I set the ip and dns domains

Comment: When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.